# Calculate difference

Tags: math, average

I have 5 values, for example like this:

```
3
11
8
5
8
```

I want to calculate the average difference between them.

If I had just two values, say 3 and 11, the difference would be 8.

But how do I do this when I have more values (for example five as in my example above)?

Comment: What you're looking for is called *standard deviation*, which is closely linked to the variance.

Comment: The question is off-topic.  The question, and both answers posted as I write this, are programming-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not show the answer in detail because I can not format math in this board. Please refer to the [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) subboard for math related question.

Not exactly sure what you are after but it might be the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)
The standard deviation is a measure of the relative deviation from each number with respect to the ensemble average.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Do you think you could post some pseudo code?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Variance](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html) or [Standard Deviation](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/standarddeviation.asp).

[Variance](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/variance.asp) -> A measure of the dispersion of a set of data points around their mean value. Variance is a mathematical expectation of the average squared deviations from the mean.

[Estimating the variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Estimating_the_variance)